# Increment score only when the user's answer is correct

Tags: php, mysqli

Im a student and new to php. Im currently working on a skill test project where scores in different categories (which are ABM, HUMSS, STEM, GAS, TVL) are counted. The problem is the scores still increment even when the user's answer is wrong. I hope someone can help me fix my codes..

**results.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$ans = $_POST['ans'];
$abmscore = 0;
$humssscore = 0;
$stemscore = 0;
$gasscore = 0;
$tvlscore = 0;

if( !empty($ans)):
  foreach($ans as $qID => $qVal) {
  $qID =  (int) $qID;
  $qVal = (int) $qVal;

$query1= "SELECT COUNT(*) AS rightAnswer FROM tquestions WHERE test_id = $qID AND correctanswer = $qVal";
$result1= mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$query2 = "SELECT strand FROM tquestions WHERE test_id = $qID";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
$strand = $row2['strand'];
if (!$result2) {
  printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
  exit();
}

if($row1['rightAnswer']) {
    if($strand == 'ABM' )  {
      $abmscore++;
    }

    elseif ($strand == 'HUMSS' ) {
      $humssscore++;
    }

    elseif ($strand == 'STEM' ) {
      $stemscore++;
    }

    elseif ($strand == 'GAS' ) {
      $gasscore++;
    }

    elseif ($strand == 'TVL' ) {
      $tvlscore++;
    }      
} 

}
endif;
}
```

**test.php**

```
$sql = "SELECT test_id, question, optiona, optionb, optionc, optiond FROM tquestions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 50";      
$result = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);
if (!$result) {
   printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
exit();
}

<form action="results.php" method="POST">
        <?php if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0): ?>
        <?php $index = 1; $num = 1; ?>
            <?php foreach ($result as $results):
                $question = $results['question'];
                $optiona = $results['optiona'];
                $optionb = $results['optionb'];
                $optionc = $results['optionc'];
                $optiond = $results['optiond'];
                $test_id = $results['test_id'];
            ?>
                <div id="q<?php echo ($index++); ?>" class="tabcontent">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="form-group">   
                            <h3 name="ques[<?php echo $test_id;?>]" style="text-indent: 40px;"> <?php echo $num,'. ', $question; ?> </h3>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="form-group">
                            <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                                 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $test_id;?>]" value="<?php echo $optiona;?>"><?php echo $optiona;?> 
                            </label>
                            <br>
                            <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                                 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $test_id;?>]" value="<?php echo $optionb;?>"><?php echo $optionb;?> 
                            </label>
                            <br>
                            <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                                 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $test_id;?>]" value="<?php echo $optionc;?>"><?php echo $optionc;?> 
                            </label>
                            <br>
                            <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                                 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $test_id;?>]" value="<?php echo $optiond;?>"><?php echo $optiond;?>
                            </label>
                            <br>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>                    
            <?php $num++; ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <br>

        <div class="form-group"><center>
            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit your answers?')"></center>
        </div>
```

*Here is my database table of test questions:*

[image: testquestions table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot packed in here and I have tested it to be successful, but if anyone finds a flaw, let me know and I'll fix it up.

This is the database table data that I am working with:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/036c06/1/0

This is my test.php code:

```
if (!$conn=new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db)) {
    echo "Database Connection Error: " , $conn->connect_error;  // don't show error messages to the public
} elseif (!$result = $conn->query('SELECT test_id, question, optiona, optionb, optionc, optiond FROM tquestions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50')) {
    echo "Syntax Error: " , $conn->error;  // don't show error messages to the public
} elseif (!$result->num_rows) {
    echo "Logic Error: No Rows @ Questions Query";
} else {
    echo "<form action=\"results.php\" method=\"POST\">";
        $i = 0;
        while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<div id=\"q",++$index,"\" class=\"tabcontent\">";
                echo "<table class=\"table table-hover\">";
                    echo "<tbody>";
                        echo "<tr class=\"form-group\">";
                            echo "<h3 name=\"ques{$row['test_id']}\" style=\"text-indent:40px;\"> " , ++$i , ". {$row['question']} </h3>"; // can't see a reason to have a name attribute here
                        echo "</tr>";
                        $options = [$row['optiona'],$row['optionb'],$row['optionc'],$row['optiond']];
                        shuffle($options);  // shuffle the options to improve test structure
                        echo "<tr class=\"form-group\">";
                            foreach ($options as $option) {
                                echo "<label class=\"radio-inline\" style=\"text-indent:70px;font-size:18px;\">&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                                    echo "<input style=\"font-size:18px;\" type=\"radio\" name=\"ans[{$row['test_id']}]\" value=\"$option\">$option";
                                echo "</label><br>";
                            }
                        echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</tbody>";
                echo "</table>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
        echo "<div class=\"form-group\">";
            echo "<center><input class=\"btn btn-success\" type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit your answers?')\"></center>";
        echo "</div>";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

Some notes:

- I don't like to bounce in and out of php, so I just stay inside php and echo everything out (personal preference).
- I have elected to use object-oriented mysqli syntax (personal preference).
- I have removed the `name` attribute on the `<h3>` tag because I don't see the benefit.  If you have a reason, just re-add it.
- I have shuffled the options for each question so that the test seems "fresh" each time.
- I have displayed the options in a loop to make the code more DRY.

This is my results.php code:

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['ans'])) {
    echo "Insufficient Submission Data Received";
} elseif (!$conn=new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db)) {
    echo "Database Connection Error: ",$conn->connect_error;
} else {
    $params = array_keys($_POST['ans']);  // collect test_ids from submission data
    $results = array('ABM'=>0,'HUMSS'=>0,'STEM'=>0,'GAS'=>0,'TVL'=>0);  // init / zero-out the categories

    $count = count($params);  // number of fullstring matches
    $csph = implode(',',array_fill(0,$count,'?'));  // comma-separated placeholders

    if (!$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT test_id,strand,correctanswer FROM tquestions WHERE test_id IN ($csph);")) {
        echo "Syntax Error @ prepare: " , $conn->error;  // don't show error messages to the public
    } else {
        array_unshift($params, str_repeat('s', $count));  // prepend the type values string
        $ref = [];  // add references
        foreach ($params as $i=>$v) {
            $ref[$i] = &$params[$i];  // pass by reference as required/advised by the manual
        }
        call_user_func_array([$stmt, 'bind_param'], $ref);    

        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            echo "Error @ bind_param/execute: ",$conn->error;
        } elseif (!$stmt->bind_result($test_id,$strand,$correctanswer)) {
            echo "Error @ bind_result: " , $stmt->error;  // don't show error messages to the public
        } else {
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                if (isset($_POST['ans'][$test_id], $results[$strand]) && $_POST['ans'][$test_id] == $correctanswer) {
                    ++$results[$strand];
                }
            }
            $stmt->close();
            var_export($results);
        }
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- I am only doing some basic submission checking at the start of the script.  you can make additional refinements if you are so inclined.
- As a matter of database protection, I use a prepared statement to query the database with user-provided data.  Unfortunately, the process of generating a "safe" `IN` clause is rather verbose.  You don't need to "understand" all of the components involved with `call_user_func_array()` if you are just beginning your journey with php.  You may just trust it for now, and research it later when you want to wrap your head around it.
- I decided to store the categorical correct answer tally as an array of data, rather than individual variables since it is a set of data with the same uniform structure.
- If you wonder about the data assigned to particular values in my scripts, just write some strategically placed `echo`s or `var_export()`s on the variables.

When I submit a "perfect" form to result.php, this is the `$_POST` data:

```
array ( 1 => '1 and 0', 8 => 'Marcelo del Pilar', 7 => 'Marcelo del Pilar', 3 => 'Liability', 5 => 'Variable', 4 => 'Crisis', 6 => 'Marcelo del Pilar', )
```

and this is the `$results` data:

```
array ( 'ABM' => 1, 'HUMSS' => 1, 'STEM' => 1, 'GAS' => 3, 'TVL' => 1, )
```

Comment: @Dza There is a lot in this.  If you have questions, find an error, or would like further clarification, please leave me a comment and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer. Since Im new to php, your codes are a bit complicated for me and Im having a hard time adapting the codes.. But anyway I tried running the codes above and it seems that all the test questions are displayed in one page. I forgot to tell you that Im using tabs and each tab must display one random question only.. and also, when I tried answering the test, the scores are not stored to the database.

Comment: I cannot provide further code for an UPDATE on the scores table because you didnt provide any detail for that.  Please improve your question to include more details for what needs to accomplished.

Comment: Forget the codes for UPDATE, I'll be finding ways to work on that, and since my question is all about incrementing scores. But can you help me display only one question on each tab, with your codes ?

Comment: Well, if you are going to have 50 questions from the database and "only show 1 at a time" then it is best to call the database just one time, and "hide" the subsequent questions with javascript/jquery until they should come into focus.  See what I mean?  It would be poor coding practice to make 50 separate queries (1 question at a time) PLUS you might risk retrieving a duplicate question.

Comment: I suppose I'd recommend Previous and Next buttons on the form, so that the user can bounce forward and backward while clicking radio buttons.  You wouldn't want form to move onto the next question as soon as a radio button was clicked because the user may change there mind.

Comment: jquery's `show()` and `hide()` calls make this task very easy to code.  You will find many tutorials and pages on SO regarding this topic.  Unfortunately, this is breaking away from the original question of this page, so you will be better to take some time to research and attempt to self-solve and then post a new question if you require support.

Comment: But in my codes above, I only have one query in calling the questions from the database and it was working perfectly fine in displaying one random question at a time.

Comment: I kept your div id in place.  However, I did remove your `name="ques[$test_id;]"`  but I mentioned this in my answer.  If you re-add this attribute, does it work?

Comment: @Dza I just re-added your `<h3>` name attribute to my answer.  Does this fix your project?

Comment: and I just noticed that I didn't write a closing quote for the div id value.  Fixed.

Comment: ^^^^^---- that typo was surely causing a problem because the code would have rendered like: `id="q1 class="tabcontent"` instead of `id="q1"` and `class="tabcontent"`  My mistake.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort helping me solve this problem. I'll just vote this up for now because I need to rush to school. I'll be back and try working on your edits and possibly accept this as the solution to my question.

Comment: @Dza 30% of all php questions on StackOverflow do not have an accepted answer.  This means they are deemed unanswered by the system.  Let's not allow this question to become abandoned.  Please let me know if my latest edit fixed your problem.  If you are still having issues, please drop me a comment to explain.

Answer (score 0):

edited:

Okay, this may need some explanation afterward, but I believe I've found a solution for you. Your code, as you have it now, gives all of your radio options the same name: `ans<?php echo $test_id ?>`. By doing this, you're passing all 4 options at once to the same variable. That's an issue.

Change the names of your inputs to be unique, and also pass test_id to results.php in a hidden input:

```
<tr class="form-group">
  <input type="hidden" name="test_id" value="<?php echo $test_id ?>">
<label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
  <input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="option_a" value="<?php echo $optiona;?>"><?php echo $optiona;?> 
</label>
<br>
<label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
  <input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="option_b" value="<?php echo $optionb;?>"><?php echo $optionb;?> 
</label>
<br>
<label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
  <input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="option_c" value="<?php echo $optionc;?>"><?php echo $optionc;?> 
</label>
<br>
<label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
  <input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="option_d" value="<?php echo $optiond;?>"><?php echo $optiond;?>
</label>
<br>
</tr>
```

Then update your test.php like to check WHICH radio was selected and grab the test_id from that hidden field:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['option_a'])) $ans = $_POST['option_a'];
    if (isset($_POST['option_b'])) $ans = $_POST['option_b'];
    if (isset($_POST['option_c'])) $ans = $_POST['option_c'];
    if (isset($_POST['option_d'])) $ans = $_POST['option_d'];
    if (isset($_POST['test_id'])) $id = $_POST['test_id'];
```

Then remove your foreach loop and fix your SQL query to "SELECT correctanswer FROM tquestions WHERE test_id = $id", because we have all of the other info, we only need the correct answer based on the ID of the question we passed from test.php

```
$query1= "SELECT correctanswer AS rightAnswer FROM tquestions WHERE test_id = $id";
```

In the end, results.php should look like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['option_a']) $ans = $_POST['option_a'];
    if (isset($_POST['option_b']) $ans = $_POST['option_b'];
    if (isset($_POST['option_c']) $ans = $_POST['option_c'];
    if (isset($_POST['option_d']) $ans = $_POST['option_d'];
    if (isset($_POST['test_id'])) $id = $_POST['test_id'];
    $abmscore = 0;
    $humssscore = 0;
    $stemscore = 0;
    $gasscore = 0;
    $tvlscore = 0;

    $query1= "SELECT correctanswer AS rightAnswer FROM tquestions WHERE test_id = $id";
    $result1= mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $query2 = "SELECT strand FROM tquestions WHERE test_id = $id";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $strand = $row2['strand'];
    if (!$result2) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
        exit();
    }

    if($ans == $row1['rightAnswer']) {
        if($strand == 'ABM')  {
          $abmscore++;
        }
        elseif ($strand == 'HUMSS') {
          $humssscore++;
        }
        elseif ($strand == 'STEM') {
          $stemscore++;
        }
        elseif ($strand == 'GAS') {
          $gasscore++;
        }
        elseif ($strand == 'TVL') {
          $tvlscore++;
        }
    }
}
```

Your test.php had some unnecessary things in it. You don't need to use  for every line of PHP code. You only need to open it and close it between parsing other languages like HTML. If you'd like me to explain further I'd be happy, but for now, I've tweaked test.php:

```
$sql = "SELECT test_id, question, optiona, optionb, optionc, optiond FROM tquestions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 50";      
$result = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);
if (!$result) {
   printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
exit();
}

<form action="results.php" method="POST">
    <?php if (!mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) die('No data');
    foreach ($result as $results) {
        $question = $results['question'];
        $optiona = $results['optiona'];
        $optionb = $results['optionb'];
        $optionc = $results['optionc'];
        $optiond = $results['optiond'];
        $test_id = $results['test_id'];
        } ?>
        <div id="q<?php echo ($index++); ?>" class="tabcontent">
            <table class="table table-hover">
            <tbody>
            <tr class="form-group">   
                <h3 name="ques[<?php echo $test_id;?>]" style="text-indent: 40px;"> <?php echo $num,'. ', $question; ?> </h3>
            </tr>
            <tr class="form-group">
                <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $test_id;?>]" value="<?php echo $optiona;?>"><?php echo $optiona;?> 
                </label>
                <br>
                <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $test_id;?>]" value="<?php echo $optionb;?>"><?php echo $optionb;?> 
                </label>
                <br>
                <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $test_id;?>]" value="<?php echo $optionc;?>"><?php echo $optionc;?> 
                </label>
                <br>
                <label class="radio-inline" style="text-indent: 70px; font-size: 18px;">
                 &nbsp;&nbsp;<input style="font-size: 18px;" type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $test_id;?>]" value="<?php echo $optiond;?>"><?php echo $optiond;?>
                </label>
                <br>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    <br>

    <div class="form-group"><center>
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit your answers?')"></center>
    </div>
```

For my sake, I hope this works out for you.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Chase Taylor. I tried if($ans == $row1['rightAnswer']) but the scores now dont increment.. what should i do? and thank you by the way for cleaning up my if statements :D

Comment: add this line right above that if statement and tell me what your script shows:
`echo "Your answer:  " + $ans + "\nCorrect answer: " + $row1['rightAnswer'];`

Comment: Actually, I didn't noticed this before but why do you have a foreach loop on $ans? Foreach is to loop through an array, and $ans is probably a string. I don't know for sure that your `$qID` or `$qVal` variables are getting set at all.

Maybe the output of that line will provide some insight, but it would likely be best if you show us what your database looks like.

Comment: I added the line and an error msg says "Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\palo\results.php....."

Comment: I used array in displaying the test questions randomly thats why i was told to use foreach loop on getting $ans..

Comment: Displaying test questions randomly is fine but you have to have a one picked before you check the answer or you're just gambling. Replace that last line I told you to try with this one : `foreach ($ans as $a) echo $a + "\n";` You should get a list. This would be much easier if you could go into phpMyAdmin or something and show the structure of your DB with a screenshot or something. I'm totally blind here.

Comment: Also, what does the page you're posting from look like? Can you add that code in your original post?

Comment: Yes I answered all the questions correctly before checking the answer but the scores did not increment

Comment: Please post the content of the page with your form and try to show us your database. I can't really help without that info.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand the issue, one more thing before I jump the gun though, please show me what your `$result` variable contains in `test.php`. You didn't include it in the code.

Comment: use `strcmp` for string comparison

Comment: PS: Your "correctanswer" for test_id 1 is incorrect. Might wanna fix that xD

Comment: I tried your codes above but an error occured. "syntax error, unexpected '$ans' (T_VARIABLE) in.."

Comment: LOL. I was trying out some functions of my system and forgot to change back the correct answer. Thank you for reminding me anyway XD

Comment: In query2, shouldnt it be test_id = $id?

Comment: Yes, it should be $id in query2. Oops.

unexpected $ans on which line?

Comment: In the line after if (isset($_POST['option_a']).. in results.php @ChaseTaylor

Comment: Lol FML I'm on my phone now but I missed the closing parenthesis for all of those if(isset) statements except the test_id one. Add a `)` just before `$ans =` on the first four lines after `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {`  I'll edit my answer in the morning

Comment: The scores still wont increment even after adding close parentheses. What could possibly be the problem?